# MSVC 10.0 c vs c++ differences

Tags: visual-c++, portability, c89, visual-studio-2010

I'm having difficulty compiling the C program below, It's just the begining of me trying to understand winsock.
The issue is that when compiling the program client.c, I get an error (C2143) missing ';' before 'type'
But when I re-name the source file to 'client.cpp' the program compiles with no errors or warnings.
I don't understand the syntax error that is an error in C but not C++.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define DEBUG

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define PORT "12186"
#define BUFFERLEN 512

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
        Variable Declorations
    */
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectionSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    int addrResult;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //unspecified so we can be compatible with IPv4 and IPv6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("IPPROTO_TCP: %d", IPPROTO_TCP);
    #endif

    //Buffers
    char * sendbuffer; // Error C2143
    char recievebuffer [BUFFERLEN]; //Error C2143

    //Initialize Winsock
    addrResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(addrResult !=0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d", addrResult);
    }
    addrResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &result);
    if(addrResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d", addrResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
C variable declorations have to go before all other code in MSVC C functions.
Problem solved.
Is this a C89 thing or is it just MSVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be the place where variable declarations are going. Place them at the beginning of the function with the other variables.

[See the last example from MSDN that can cause this error code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx)

Comment: "In a C program, variables must be declared at the beginning of the function, and they cannot be declared after the function executes non-declaration instructions."
Thanks! Moving the variable declarations above the setting values for hints allowed the c compiler to compile with no error.

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler which ships with VS only implements C89 (seriously...), so you must declare all of your variables at the top of a given function.